# I can't seem to import tensorflow to python VSCODE

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, pip

Traceback (*most recent call last*):

```
File "d:\kuliah\aa\aaa\aaaa\bpnn.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf

File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\sitepackages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module> from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import

File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 59, in <module> from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *

File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

This happened when I'm importing my tensorflow on a .py code, what am i missing?

Comment: How did you install tensorflow (and python)?

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs beacuse `VScode` and `Coderunner` extension can not activate the `conda` environment you are using. To fix this.

1. Start `anaconda command prompt` then type in `activate <your environment name>`
2. Type in `code` to start `VSCode`. Your import should be working now.

Thanks!